# Error in converting NSString to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a NSString which contains date in following format: Nov 19, 2015 10:44 AM

Now I am trying to convert NSString to NSDate using following block of code:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm a "];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
NSDate *setEditDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:lastLog];
NSLog(@"setEditDate = %@",setEditDate);
```

Above code returns me "setEditDate = 2015-11-19 00:44:00 +0000"

Here time gets changed, 10:44 to 00:44.

How can I fix this issue, to get correct date and time.
Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: is it has to do with the timezone?

Comment: Yes. Beacuse If I remove timezone formater, I get following result
setEditDate = 2015-11-18 19:14:00 +0000
1 day less from the given date

Comment: Change `@"MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm a "` to `@"MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a"`

Comment: Could you please provide us the string `lastLog`.

Comment: can you post the string 'lastLog'

Comment: xcode is known to exhibit bug when u convert NSDate to NSString previously. I myself have been in this issue for days only to understand this.

Comment: Changing @"MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm a " to @"MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a" worked
lastlog Nov 19, 2015 10:44 AM
setEditDate 2015-11-19 10:44:00 +0000

Comment: NSDate is time zone neutral... its date formatter that changes date with time zone... if you want time as in string then dont set formatter with time zone GMT cause this convert time according to GMT.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your format string is slightly wrong.  Instead of `HH` for the hours, you want `hh`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, is the code which I used. And the code is already working.

```
NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a "];
NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
NSLog(@"localDateString : %@",localDateString);
```

I hope it Helps.